# How to write a multi-layer query?

Tags: sql, database

I have a list of items. I am trying to extract a particular subset from.

All entries in the table that match:

Has entry in varereg.variantav.

Has entry in varereg.varenr that matches the entry's in varereg.variantav.

varereg.variantav refers to other items in varereg.varenr.

I get all the goods that have a value in the varereg.variantav. By using:

```
Where 
varereg.variantav IS NOT NULL and 
varereg.variantav not like '';
```

but I would also like to use the value stored in varereg.variantav to pick up more items from varereg.varenr.

```
Where 
varereg.variantav in (  select 
variantav 
from 
varereg group by variantav having count(*) >=1);
```

Unfortunately, I'm not good enough with SQL to combine them. any suggestions?

this is the best I've gotten to.

```
select 
varereg.varenr as                            Vare_nr,
varereg.varenavn as                          Vare_navn,
varereg.hovedgrp as                          Hovedg_nr,
vkat.katnavn as                              Hovedg_navn,
varereg.undergrp as                          Underg_nr,
vunderkat.ukatnavn as                        Underg_navn,
varereg.aktivvare as                         Aktiv,
varereg.webaktiv as                          Web_Aktiv,
varereg.Tilbud as                            Tilbud,
ISNULL(varemultikat.webshopvaregruppe, 0) as Multi_Aktiv,
ISNULL(vkat2.hovedgrp, 0) as                 Multi_Hovedg_nr,
ISNULL(vkat2.katnavn, '0') as                Multi_Hovedg_navn,
ISNULL(vunderkat2.Undergrp, 0) as            Multi_Underg_nr,
ISNULL(vunderkat2.ukatnavn, '0') as          Multi_Underg_navn,
varereg.id as                                Vare_ID,
vkat.id as                                   Hovedg_ID,
vunderkat.id as                              Underg_ID,
varereg.variantav


From 
varereg 
left outer join vkat on                    varereg.vkatid=vkat.id 
left outer join vunderkat on               varereg.vunderkatid=vunderkat.id
left outer join varemultikat on            varereg.id=varemultikat.vareid
left outer join vkat as vkat2 on           varemultikat.vkatid=vkat2.id 
left outer join vunderkat as vunderkat2 on varemultikat.vunderkatid=vunderkat2.id 

Where 
varereg.variantav IS NOT NULL and 
varereg.variantav not like '' and 
varereg.variantav like '996618-MAL' or
varereg.varenr like '996618-MAL'
;
```

[shows the result of query in the text placed above this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zio1I.png)

```
 and 
varereg.variantav like '996618-MAL' or
varereg.varenr like '996618-MAL'
```

is placed in the query to limit the search and provoke the desired result. as shown in the picture.

---

I certainly was not clear enough when I explained what I needed.

clarifying what I was trying to sayunder here:

```
SELECT
    v.varenr AS Vare_nr,
    v.varenavn AS Vare_navn,
    v.hovedgrp AS Hovedg_nr,
    vk.katnavn AS Hovedg_navn,
    v.undergrp AS Underg_nr,
    vuk.ukatnavn AS Underg_navn,
    v.aktivvare AS Aktiv,
    v.webaktiv AS Web_Aktiv,
    v.Tilbud AS Tilbud,
    ISNULL(vm.webshopvaregruppe, 0) AS Multi_Aktiv,
    ISNULL(vk2.hovedgrp, 0) AS Multi_Hovedg_nr,
    ISNULL(vk2.katnavn, '0') AS Multi_Hovedg_navn,
    ISNULL(vuk2.Undergrp, 0) AS Multi_Underg_nr,
    ISNULL(vuk2.ukatnavn, '0') AS Multi_Underg_navn,
    v.id AS Vare_ID,
    vk.id AS Hovedg_ID,
    vuk.id AS Underg_ID,
    v.variantav
FROM 
    varereg v

    LEFT JOIN vkat vk ON v.vkatid = vk.id 
    LEFT JOIN vunderkat vuk ON v.vunderkatid = vuk.id
    LEFT JOIN varemultikat vm ON v.id = vm.vareid
    LEFT JOIN vkat vk2 ON vm.vkatid = vk2.id 
    LEFT JOIN vunderkat vuk2 ON v.vunderkatid = vuk2.id 
WHERE 
    v.variantav IS NOT NULL
    AND v.variantav <> ''
```

The code above works fine. but I need some more connected to the same query

I wish the result of this linked to the end of the query.

```
WHERE 
    (v.variantav IS NOT NULL
    AND v.variantav <> '') OR 

v.varenr like (

select 
variantav

from 
varereg 
group by variantav
having count(*) >=1

)
```

Comment: (varereg.variantav IS NOT NULL and varereg.variantav <> '' and varereg.variantav = '996618-MAL') or varereg.varenr = '996618-MAL'

Comment: To be fair the logic here doesn't really matter anyway... as the `IS NULL` and `<> ""` is implied by `= '996618-MAL'`.

Comment: like '996618-MAL'

is placed in the query to limit the search and provoke the desired result. as shown in the picture.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the subtle change in column name, my Danish isn't good enough I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I had to refactor your query a little, as the style was bugging me :D

```
SELECT
    v.varenr AS Vare_nr,
    v.varenavn AS Vare_navn,
    v.hovedgrp AS Hovedg_nr,
    vk.katnavn AS Hovedg_navn,
    v.undergrp AS Underg_nr,
    vuk.ukatnavn AS Underg_navn,
    v.aktivvare AS Aktiv,
    v.webaktiv AS Web_Aktiv,
    v.Tilbud AS Tilbud,
    ISNULL(vm.webshopvaregruppe, 0) AS Multi_Aktiv,
    ISNULL(vk2.hovedgrp, 0) AS Multi_Hovedg_nr,
    ISNULL(vk2.katnavn, '0') AS Multi_Hovedg_navn,
    ISNULL(vuk2.Undergrp, 0) AS Multi_Underg_nr,
    ISNULL(vuk2.ukatnavn, '0') AS Multi_Underg_navn,
    v.id AS Vare_ID,
    vk.id AS Hovedg_ID,
    vuk.id AS Underg_ID,
    v.variantav
FROM 
    varereg v
    INNER JOIN (SELECT variantav FROM varereg GROUP BY variantav HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1) x ON x.variantav = v.variantav
    LEFT JOIN vkat vk ON v.vkatid = vkat.id 
    LEFT JOIN vunderkat vuk ON v.vunderkatid = vuk.id
    LEFT JOIN varemultikat vm ON v.id = vm.vareid
    LEFT JOIN vkat vk2 ON vm.vkatid = vk2.id 
    LEFT JOIN vunderkat vuk2 ON v.vunderkatid = vuk2.id 
WHERE 
    v.variantav IS NOT NULL
    AND v.variantav <> '';
```

The key is the `INNER JOIN` to x, as this adds the logic you asked for.  I'm not really sure why you were limiting to a single `variantav`, so I assumed this was for testing purposes and could be ignored?

---

Okay, I totally misunderstood your question it appears.  I'm afraid I re-read it a few times and I'm still not getting it.

You said that you want a query that does all of the below.

All entries in the table that match:

- Has entry in varereg.variantav.
- Has entry in varereg.varenr that matches the entry's in varereg.variantav.
- varereg.variantav refers to other items in varereg.varenr.

So the first part seems okay, you want items that have an entry in your product table for `variantav` (unsure how this translates).  Your solution is to check for `NULL` and also for empty strings, rejecting both of these.

You could also do this with `ISNULL(variantav, '') <> ''`.  Which has the advantage of not introducing logical operators (`AND`, `OR`), which keeps things simpler.

The next bit is where I am losing it.  Are you simply saying that you would accept rows where there's nothing (or `NULL`) in `variantav` but there's something in `varenr`?  Or are you saying that this is only acceptable if the value in `varenr` matches a value in `variantav` on at least one other row in your table?

I have no idea what your "find items with more than one instance, i.e. duplicates" query has to do with any of this.

This whole query could be massively simplified by the way, as the `LEFT JOIN`s are all just "chatter", and could be taken out then added back in when you have something that works.

So your original query becomes:

```
SELECT
    v.variantav,
    v.varenr
FROM 
    varereg v
WHERE 
    --ISNULL(v.variantav, '') <> '' (unnecessary with explicit value defined)
    v.variantav = '996618-MAL' 
    OR v.varenr = '996618-MAL';
```

If you want what I know think you want (but I am <50% confident this IS actually what you want now) then you could do something this:

```
SELECT
    v.variantav,
    v.varenr
FROM 
    varereg v
WHERE 
    ISNULL(v.variantav, '') <> ''
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM varereg v2 WHERE v2.variantav = v.varenr);
```

Am I getting closer?

---

Aha, we both edited at the same time!

I think you need to simply add this logic:

```
SELECT
    v.variantav,
    v.varenr
FROM 
    varereg v
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT variantav FROM varereg GROUP BY variantav HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x ON x.variantav = v.varenr
WHERE 
    ISNULL(v.variantav, '') <> ''
    OR x.variantav IS NOT NULL;
```

That's not your whole query, so just add back all the other `SELECT` columns and the `LEFT JOIN`s and you should be good to go?

Comment: 'LEFT JOIN vkat vk ON v.vkatid = vkat.id' is wrong. 'LEFT JOIN vkat vk ON v.vkatid = vk.id'

Comment: Yes, I missed that one, good spot!  Does the query work with that fixed though?

Comment: Not quite. the 'INNER JOIN' makes 'WHERE' unnecessary. and I certainly was not clear enough when I explained what I needed. and block other results I want to get connected to query

Comment: I think I understand what you want now... I hope!

Comment: are not sure what you mean by `OR EXISTS` but it looks right. I'll try something now.

Comment: As I have said, I am new to this. Thanks.
I did not remember what I was looking for when I started writing this and when I tried to clarify things.